# Laravel - Using different field names in the database (userid in a table and created_by in other)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use a table for my Users and separate table for users' Projects in my database. However I want the names of the fields to be different for user id. What I want to take the `id` from the 'Users' table; and while saving the created project to the database, use that (user) `id` as `created_by_id` in Projects table.

```
public function store(CreateProjectRequest $request)
{
    $project = new Project($request->all());

    Auth::user()->projects()->save($project);

     // Project::create($request->all());

    return redirect('pages/home');
}
```

Also in `Users.php`, I added:

```
public function projects()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
 }
```

The commented field is working on its own. However, I guess my problem arises because when I comment that line again, and add the other two lines (`$project...` and `Auth::user...` bits), I guess it is assuming I have a field in the Projects table named id.

I thought I would work around this problem with changing the primary key but I couldn't find how to take the Auth::user()->id; and make it write that value in `created_by_id` in a secure way. This is what I found though:

```
 class Project extends Eloquent {

   protected $primaryKey = 'created_by_id';

}
```

**Edit: I don't think changing the primary key is my solution.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a second and third parameter to `hasMany()` method to specify the keys to use. [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article','userid','created_by');
}
```

Comment: I added it in my code. However it is still not saving the `created_by` field in database. `$table->integer('created_by_id')->unsigned();` this is how my migration file is. When I dd($projects), it detects the field as fillable but it doesn't return any value. Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried `$this->hasMany('App\Article','userid','created_by_id');` in `projects()`? I think if you explicitly pass the keys, Laravel won't add the **_id** automatically.